# TFS Build with dotnet restore and 4.5 Project

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a .Net CORE (Framework) Project that I want to build and deploy using TFS. I do a Nuget Restore Task first on the solution and than run MSBuild Solution with the following argument

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" (Visual Studio Version 2015)

I get the **Please run "dotnet restore" to generate a new lock file.** message but I cannot run that because there is a library that is referenced that is 4.5 and the dotnet cli errors on that project. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Which build are you using XAML or Vnext ? And what's your TFS version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, XAML and VSO hosted

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT see above

Answer (score 1):

No workaround for this situation, you have to run dotnet restore.

> This behavior is by design. […] If you wish to restore all of the dependencies for all your projects in one go, so to speak, just run `dotnet restore` at the root of your solution (where you have the `global.json` file).
>
> *[From Zlatko Knezevic](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4065#issuecomment-241037969):*

As for your  "mixed" solution with 4.5, it's not support by ASP.NET Core 1.0  with msbuild.
[image]

You could also take a look at this simialr issue in GITHub: [dotnet restore unable to resolve .NET Framework libraries (4.5.2)](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3199)